# convert and substring together in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help to correct syntax in sql query.

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY symmetrickey_ccprocessing
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE certificate_ccprocessing;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, DECRYPTBYKEY(c.CR_CARD_NBR)) AS CR_CARD_NBR
from dbo.credit C
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY symmetrickey_ccprocessing;
```

I need first two characters of column CR_CARD_NBR.
How can I use string and convert with decrypt key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should get in the habit of specifying the scale of varchars. When you don't specify a size it uses the default which can vary by usage. In a select it will be 30, as a parameter it will be 1. Avoid the hassle and be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enclose it with Left(xxx,2) like so;

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY symmetrickey_ccprocessing
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE certificate_ccprocessing;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DECRYPTBYKEY(c.CR_CARD_NBR)),2) AS CR_CARD_NBR
from dbo.credit C
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY symmetrickey_ccprocessing;
```